# LongPressGestureRecognizer recognize from behind the views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, viewcontroller

I have MainViewController and LongPressGestureRecognizer added to MainViewController's view.

When I call my CategoryViewController by adding as a child view controller of MainViewController like below, as a longpress gesture action.

```
- (IBAction)longPressClicked:(id)sender {
    _categoryVC = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    _categoryVC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self addChildViewController:_categoryVC];
    [_categoryVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

I'm tapping long press first time to screen It loads CategoryViewController to child controller and pushes to top which is fine, but I'm doing same thing again and `longPressClicked` method calls again.

I wonder why does it do that because CategoryViewController on the top of the view and It has UserInteractionEnabled on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action gets called multiple times. Every time when

- the gesture gets recognised (touch down for a specific time)
- the gesture has ended (lift up)
- the gesture has detected a change (a finger moved)

And every time you add a view.

So when you touch down, you add a view and when you lift up you add a view again. Besides your gesture recogniser **doesn't cancel** the touch tracking only because you add a view above the touch location. It still handles the touches. To prevent this just consider the state of your gesture as follows

```
- (IBAction)longPressClicked:(id)sender {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;

     if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // add your view
     }
}
```

Another option is to keep a weak reference of your view and check if your view is nil. If so create a new view and add it to your view controller's subview.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
@end

- (void)longPressClicked:(id)sender {
    if (!self.myView) {
      // create view
      self.myView = [[UIView alloc] init....]; 
    }
}
```